# Is there a Latex symbol that looks like a sector ⌔ of a circle?

Tags: symbols

In Unicode, I can find the symbol U+2314 SECTOR:

### ⌔

[image: rendering from the official Unicode chart]

Is there something similar in LaTeX?

Comment: You could draw it with `pict2e`, just a two `\line`s and one `\arc`. @Mico It's an unicode character.

Comment: Oh no, the wi-fi signal is down!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
```

[image]

I just searched [The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiEv4_2nebMAhXJGh4KHfPBC7IQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftug.ctan.org%2Finfo%2Fsymbols%2Fcomprehensive%2Fsymbols-a4.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGCQeIwjbEo-cV_eZX4g9Aze09VNQ&sig2=Mbd2xw7S1Q9K3JhMmTPqVA) and found it.

Comment: Note you will have to be in math mode: `$\downslice$`.

Comment: Good but with the same caveat @egreg pointed out to Thomas' answer above: `MnSymbol` will change _a lot_ of other symbols too.

Comment: Under `MnSymbol`, there are also \upslice, \leftslice, and \rightslice.

Comment: The package `MnSymbol` changes `\Im` from the `physics` package.

Answer (score 20):

This is an implementation using `pict2e`; the angle is 40 degrees.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sector}{\mathord{\mathpalette\make@sector\relax}}
\newcommand{\make@sector}[2]{%
  \settoheight{\unitlength}{$#1x$}%
  \begin{picture}(1,1.06)
  \linethickness{.08\unitlength}
  \moveto(0.5,0)
  \lineto(0.842,1)
  \curveto(.6,1.08)(.4,1.08)(0.158,1)
  \closepath
  \strokepath
  \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\sector x$

$A_{x\sector}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 17):

There is a symbol from the `fdsymbol` package called `\sector`.

Also, depending on your level of desperation, you might want to look through [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-letter.pdf).

[image]

Comment: Beware that `fdsymbol` changes almost all symbols.

Answer (score 8):

The symbol drawn with `pgf`. The size (`\SectorRadius`), the angle (`\SectorHalfAngle`), and the line width (`\SectorLineWidth`) can be configured:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\newcommand*{\SectorRadius}{1ex}
\newcommand*{\SectorHalfAngle}{45}
\newcommand*{\SectorLineWidth}{.4pt}

\newcommand*{\sector}{%
  \begin{pgfpicture}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgforigin}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointpolar{90-(\SectorHalfAngle)}{\SectorRadius}}%
    \pgfarc{90-(\SectorHalfAngle)}{90+\SectorHalfAngle}{\SectorRadius}%
    \pgfpathclose
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\SectorLineWidth}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}%
  \end{pgfpicture}%
}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{lc}
    Symbol:   & \sector\\
    Bolder:   & \renewcommand*{\SectorLineWidth}{1pt}\sector\\
    Larger:   & \pgfmathsetlengthmacro\SectorRadius{height("h")}\sector\\
    Narrower: & \renewcommand*{\SectorHalfAngle}{30}\sector\\
    Wider:    & \renewcommand*{\SectorHalfAngle}{60}\sector\\
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with some variants]

Comment: Great answer! Is there some way to rotate the symbol 90 clockwise? So it is oriented more like an angle symbol?

Comment: @Mathemanic `\rotatebox` of package `graphics/graphicx`, or `\sector` can be redefined (instead of the more low-level `pgfpicture` commands, the rotated `\sector` can also be defined using `tikzpicture`.

Comment: I tried using \rotatebox and it rotated successfully, but it ended up drawn strangely below the text line.

Answer (score 3):

You can find a font that has that Unicode symbol (see the list at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2314/fontsupport.htm), install it as a system font, load it using `fontspec`, and put that symbol directly in your `.tex` file. Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX instead of pdfLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria}

\begin{document}
Here is the symbol: ⌔
\end{document}
```

[image]